# missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column in DataFrame which contains the characters “()”, I would like to remove / delete all the char with in (), including (). How do I do it?

My DataFrame looks something like this

```
Emp_Name - 
S Kerody (IND)
R Ray (NZ)
TR Brett (NZ)
M John (AUS)
B Maddy (AUS)
```

I want the coulmn to be (Expected O/P) -
Emp_Name

```
S Kerody
R Ray
TR Brett
M John
B Maddy
```

Comment: You can use `Series.str.extract` or `Series.str.replace`

Comment: If you have a pipeline which pre-process the data, you can use sed : `sed -e 's/ (.*)//g'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use replace with a regex that matches parenthesis and stuff inside:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Emp_Name':['S Kerody (IND)','R Ray (NZ)','TR Brett (NZ)','M John (AUS)','B Maddy (AUS)']})
df['Emp_Name'] = df['Emp_Name'].str.replace(r'\(.*\)', '', regex = True)
df
```

produces

```
    Emp_Name
0   S Kerody
1   R Ray
2   TR Brett
3   M John
4   B Maddy
```

Comment: Great! @user9453872 you should then consider whether you want to accept the answer formally, and pls see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for future reference